# Android Google Maps Api v2 SupportMapFragment.getMap() returns null in Android Studio but NOT in Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-studio, google-maps-api-2

While I have seen many posts concerning a SupportMapFragment returning a null map on .getMap(), I haven't seen any posts with this particular issue. Forgive me if I'm wrong, but any help is appreciated.

I have a project that I would like to be able to work on in Android Studio. Everything imports without errors. The library dependencies transfer fine, with Google Play Services being added to the build.gradle, as well as Android Support v4, as expected. Everything runs fine when running the code in the ADT IDE, however when running from Android Studio, things go wonky.

Here is my various code pertaining to the issue:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.example.areaFinder.WorkaroundMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**WorkAroundMapFragment.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class WorkaroundMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    private OnTouchListener mListener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstance) {
        View layout = super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, viewGroup, savedInstance);

        TouchableWrapper frameLayout = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());

        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

        ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(frameLayout,
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        return layout;
    }

    public void setListener(OnTouchListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnTouchListener {
        public abstract void onTouch();
    }

    public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {

        public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mListener.onTouch();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mListener.onTouch();
                break;
            }
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java (onCreate() Method)**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // This is returning null from Android Studio but not Eclipse
    map = ((WorkaroundMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    mMarkers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    ...
}
```

The only error message I receive says that the function .getMap() is returning null, with otherwise useless information.

Thanks for any help. Please let me know if I have made an error in asking the question appropriately.

Comment: Don't you need to attach your fragment to an activity somewhere before calling getMap()?

Comment: @Barodapride The fragment is created in the activity_main.xml as you can see above, I am simply retrieving it with its id (R.id.map)

Comment: I think I may have experienced a similar problem a couple days ago in my project. Try putting a dummy TextView in the xml just before your fragment element. For some reason, my project wasn't liking the fragment as the first element in my RelativeLayout. That said, I only use Eclipse.

Comment: ever find a fix for this?

Comment: Yes, there was a problem with the version of Google Play Services that Android Studio was automatically building with (a development version that wasn't installed on my tablet). I just changed the version number to a previous version and everything worked well. @user172917